# Transferring the top stack element to the first of the second stack

Tags: c++, stack

Ok, so here's my problem: I'm new to stacks in C++ and I'm trying to move the top element from one stack to the other. This is what I've come up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void firstRow(stack <int> a,int X){
for(int i=1;i<=X;i++){
    a.push(i);
}
cout<<"Row 1: ";
for(int i=1;i<=X;i++){
    cout<<a.top()<<" ";
    a.pop();
 }
}

void firstTosecond(stack <int> a,stack <int> b,int X){
int k;
k=a.top();
b.push(k);
cout<<"Row 2: ";
while(!b.empty()){
    cout<<b.top()<<" ";
    b.pop();
}

}

int main() {
int X;
stack <int> a;
stack <int> b;
cout<<"Enter a number:";
cin>>X;
firstRow(a,X);
firstTosecond(a,b,X);

return 0;   
}
```

But, when it tries to run the firstTosecond function it does a core dump. I still haven't figured out why. Maybe I haven't researched on stacks enough or I'm just ignorant on the subject but I've been stuck on this part for quite a while now.

If anyone can help me or give me any tips on what I'm doing wrong is most appreciated :).

Comment: Your C++ book should have a chapter that explains the difference between passing parameters by value, and passing parameters by reference, to a function. You should read it, until you figure out the reason why  your stacks in main will always be empty, and `firstRow()` simply adds values to a stack that gets immediately destroyed when the function returns, with `a` in `main()` still being completely empty, as it always was. Another useful chapter in your C++ book is the one that explains error checking, so before calling `top()` you'd know to check it to make sure that the stack is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing all parameters by copy. So after `firstRow(a,X);` call the stack `a` is still empty because the function operated on its own local variable = the parameter also named `a`. The code then crashes because it's not allowed to call `top` on an empty stack. Add references to the functions like this: `void firstRow(stack <int>& a,int X)`,`void firstTosecond(stack <int>& a,stack <int>& b,int X)`.